# Spark Error - cannot assign instance of SerializedLambda to field javaRDDLike of type FlatMapFunction

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, spark-submit

I’ve been trying for a while to launch a simple spring-spark app on the cluster, but I found the following problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of 
java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field 
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1.f$3 of type 
org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction in instance of 
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$1$1**
```

The app I’m trying to launch is the following:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test");
        conf.setJars(new String[]{"/home/ubuntu/spring-spark-word-count-master/target/spring-spark-word-count-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"});
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaRDD<String> words = sc.textFile("hdfs://master.vmware.local:8020/test/test.txt");

        JavaRDD<String> wordsFromFile = words.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator());

        Map<String, Long> wordCounts = wordsFromFile.countByValue();
        wordCounts.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));
        words.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://master.vmware.local:8020/test/" + String.valueOf(new Date().getTime()));
        sc.close();
    }
```

After some tests I noticed that the problem was due to flatmap. To launch the app on a cluster use the following command:

```
 spark-submit "/home/ubuntu/spring-spark-word-count-master/target/spring-spark-word-count-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

When I launch the app locally on the master node it works, while when I distribute it on the nodes it gives me the problem. I can't understand where the problem can be. Below are also the pom and the configuration of the cluster extracted from ambari:

**POM:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.paranamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>paranamer</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Cluster CONFIG:**

- HDFS        3.1.1.3.1
- YARN      3.1.1
- MapReduce2    3.1.1
- Hive      3.1.0
- Spark2        2.3.0

Comment: Make sure that the class which defined the lambda expression is also available in the runtime where the lambda is serialized. Use `conf.setJars(new String[]{"/path/to/jar/with/your/class.jar"})`

Comment: I added the configuration, but the result is the same. I updated the post with your suggestion

Comment: If I try to use Sparksession instead. It gives me the following error:

_java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD_

Comment: Does the cluster know the location of `/home/ubuntu/...`?

Comment: How can I verify this?

Comment: Use any kind of a simple `File.exists` or something like it

Comment: Thanks, but I put the jar in all the nodes at the same path as you said, but the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the way the Spring Boot builds jars ([More info here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html)).
In a nutshell jars are nested into the big jar as opposed to flatten out like in a traditional assembly/fat jar.

I do not have a solution other than not using Spring Boot jars.

Comment: I don't think this is a good enough answer. If Spring jars have entirely different format then the entire Spark application will fail, it won't even reach the point of type casting. There must be another reason